# Asp.Net Core 8 OutputCache not working with nginx reverse proxy

Tags: asp.net-core, nginx

I'm using the new [output caching middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/output?view=aspnetcore-8.0) introduced in .Net 7 (I'm running .Net 8) for my server. I have the endpoints set up correctly with .CacheOutput etc. Everything is working fine locally when I run the app on my local machine using IIS Express.

When running locally and I visit the same endpoint twice, an information log is stored stating the cache was served. I also have an additional log in the endpoint that should only be hit on the first endpoint visit before it's cached, which is the case locally (with IIS Express).

The moment I deploy the app to a remote Ubuntu server where I'm using Nginx as the reverse proxy server, no caching occurs. The logs don't show caching, and the logs register my custom log indicating the endpoint being served multiple times without a cache. This is the exact same deployed app as the one I'm running locally.

Both locally and remotely the app are running as localhost, remotely Nginx is forwarding the request to the localhost where the app is running via kestrel.

Any idea why caching is not working in my remote deployment, but it is locally?

Comment: check `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and comment out or remove any lines related to `proxy_cache`. could you check the header for the `Cache-Control` what is set to. could you also share your sample code with us